# How can I dynamically create UIButtons with Cocoa Touch?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How can I dynamically create UIButtons with Cocoa Touch?

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<10;i++) { UIButton*but=[UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.view addSubview:but]; }`, this will create the buttons, but this should be found with little research, what problems are you facing ?

Comment: Hey @Vicky, please make search first, then to post question....:)

Answer (score 1):

```
 UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 44); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
    [myButton setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // add targets and actions
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // add to a view
    [superView addSubview:myButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar - refresh.png"];
    
    refresh = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    refresh.frame = CGRectMake(frame values);
    [refresh setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    [self.view addSubview:refresh];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int yOfs = 0;
for (int index = 0; index<10; index++) {
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d",index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, yOfs, 100, 50)];
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aView addSubview:aButton];

    yOfs += 50;
}


- (IBAction)aButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Clicked on button with title %@",[sender titleLabel].text);
}
```

Comment: It is better to store your buttons in an array for your example

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btnDone;
btnDone = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnDone setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 29)];

// For setting an image to button....
[btnDone setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnDone setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done_hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

// Add target to button...
[btnDone addTarget:self action:@selector(btnDoneAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//Method implementation..
-(void)btnDoneAction:(id)sender
{
    //Your stuff..
}
```